# Calculating the $100th$ term of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across a series

$1,5,13,25,41,61.......$

I have to calculate the $100^{th}$ term of this series. How do I do it?

Is there any formula to calculate the $n^{th}$ term of a series?

Comment: You mean series or sequence ?

Comment: If you trust your lucky stars, check out [A001844](http://oeis.org/A001844). But be advised that it's by no means the *only* possible sequence which starts with those values.

Comment: @LinuxGeek: $a_n =2 n^2 - 2 n + 1$.

Comment: @dxiv My Bad ! Removed it now

Comment: @Moo How did you determine it?

Comment: Took differences twice and you see a constant difference of $4$.

Comment: @dxiv I did check oeis before asking here but the page didnt have the 100th term nor was there an explanation!

Comment: @LinuxGeek The page lists a formula for the $n^{th}$ term.

Comment: Why are some getting 19801 and some 20201?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me as though the forward difference is linear so that your equation can be given by a quadratic.

$$4,8,12,..$$

It seems as though,

$$f(x+1)-f(x)=4x+4$$

Where $f(0)=1$ (and $f(1)=5$).

So by summing both sides of this equation from $x=0$ to $n-1$ and noticing that the sum in the LHS telescopes we have,

$$f(n)-f(0)=\sum_{x=0}^{n-1} (4x+4)$$

$$f(n)=f(0)+\sum_{x=0}^{n-1} (4x+4)$$

$$f(n)=1+4\frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}+4n$$

Now if instead you want the sequence to start with $f(1)$ instead of $f(0)$, shift current $f$ to the right $1$.

$$f(n)=1+2(n-1)((n-1)-1)+4(n-1)$$

$$f(n)=2n^2-2n+1$$

So,

$$f(100)=2(100^2)-2(100)+1$$

$$=19801$$

Comment: ...so the final answer is...?

Answer (score 2):

The difference of successive terms forms an Arithmetic progression: $4,8,\cdots $.

We can write the terms of our sequence as: $$0\times 4+1,1\times 4+1, 3\times 4+1, 6\times 4+1, 10\times 4+1, \cdots $$ $$=\frac {0\times 1}{2}\times 4+1, \frac {1\times 2}{2}\times 4+1, \frac {2\times 3}{2}\times 4+1, \frac {3\times 4}{2}\times 4+1, \cdots $$

We can see a pattern emerging. Thus the $n$th term of the sequence is $$\frac {n (n-1)}{2}\times 4+1 =4\binom {n}{2} +1$$ The hundredth term is thus $\boxed {4\binom {100}{2}+1=19801}$. Hope it helps.

Comment: (0) The formula is correct but the final result is not 20201.

Comment: Thanks @TMM for correcting the typo.

Answer (score 2):

In general, there is no way to determine the $n$th term of a series.

For this series 1, 5, 13, 25, 41, 61, ...

$1 + 4\times 1 = 5$

$5 + 4\times 2 = 13$

$13 + 4\times 3 = 25$

...

$\Rightarrow f(n)=f(n-1)+4(n-1), f(0)=1 \Rightarrow f(n)=(4\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i)+1 $

$f(100)=(4\sum_{i=1}^{99}i)+1=19801$

Comment: (+1) The first one to actually get the right final answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence is $1+2n(n+1)$, so the $100^{th}$ term is $20201$.

Comment: How did you determine the sequence?

Comment: it's 1 + the n'th triangular number [n(n+1)/2] of 4's, so 1+2n(n+1). i called $a_0=1, a_1=5,\dots$ btw.

Comment: (-1) That is the 101st term.